# Select date range with awk

Tags: awk

I have list of folders with name format as YYYYMMDD and I am trying to get the subset of folders with in a date range using awk command. However it is not including folder name on the right boundary.

**List of directories:**

```
bash-4.2# ls -d */
20240111/  20240112/  20240113/  20240114/  20240115/  20240118/  20240120/  dest/  test-files/  test/
```

Note: *The folder may also contain subfolders whose name is not in YYYYMMDD format. For instance 'test-files/' as above*

**AWK command to get a range (20240114 - 20240120) of subfolder names:**

```
bash-4.2#  ls -d */ | awk -v start=20240114 -v end=20240120 '{d=substr($0,0); if (d>=start&&d<=end) print}' 
20240114/
20240115/
20240118/
```

Here, though the if condition has less than equal to condition "d<=end" the output is not including folder with name "20240120/". Not sure why this one is not included in the result.

Also, please note that I don't have much experience with advanced linux commands. So, please kindly advise if the above command is right and works always. For instance if there is any subfolder with unexpected name, is there a chance that this command returns wrong results.

Comment: What's the reason for `d=substr($0, 0)`? That's the same as `d=$0`

Comment: @Barmar: Thanks for pointing it out. So, I can just use "d=$0" here, is it correct?

Comment: Why do you even need `d`? Just use `$0 >= start && $0 <= end`

Comment: Regarding `substr($0,0)` - all field numbers, array indices, and strings in awk start at 1, not 0. When you use an invalid value like `0` or `"fluffy bunny"` in `substr()`s start position awk converts it to a default value of `1` which is why you don't see breakage as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`20240120/` collates after `20240120`, your range doesn't include it. Do it like this instead:

```
awk -F / -v start=20240114 -v end=20240120 '$1 >= start && $1 <= end'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `/` at the end of the name. `20240120/` is higher than `20240120`.

You should add it to the `start` and `end` variables.

```
ls -d */ | awk -v start=20240114/ -v end=20240120/ '{d=substr($0,0); if (d>=start&&d<=end) print}'
```

Comment: I think  `awk 'start <= $1 && $1 <= end' FS='[/]' start=20240114 end=20240120` should have same results

Answer (score 1):

> if there is any subfolder with unexpected name, is there a chance that this command returns wrong results

Yes, consider that

```
echo "2024011Z" | awk -v start=20240114 -v end=20240120 '{d=substr($0,0); if (d>=start&&d<=end) print}'
```

gives output

```
2024011Z
```

Explanation: I subverted GNU `AWK` into doing lexicographical comparison, as last character (`Z`) has higher ASCII value (0x5A) than `4` (0x34) it is consider higher than `20240114`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

> advise if the above command is right and works always.

Generally if you attempt to parse `ls` output you might expect hard time to make it *works always*, read [hackerthink.com article: Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://hackerthink.com/solutions/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead/) if you want to know more.